# VBA Variable in range

Tags: vba, excel

Hey is it possible to use a variable within a range object? 
My goal is to keep the formula that is in the excel cell, but the value of the cell itself is to be deleted.

The procedure for a better understanding:
1. search for a value, where "i" is indicating the row, where the value is found
2. delete this value, BUT: save the formula
3. another value is entered in this cell and the formula is still active and is checking some condition

Searching is no problem, but I cant delete the value of the cell without deleting the formula aswell.

This is what i tried:

```
rangeA = "D" & i

Set rConstants = Sheet1.range(rangeA).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
rConstants.ClearContents
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ranges can use variables to determine which cells they refer to, but can you clarify what it means to delete a value, but keep the formula?

Comment: I hope its clearer now

Comment: Hm... do you want to save formula in the memory so you can use it later on? Or do you want to use value later in your code? Both cases are possible. However please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to save the formula. It checks if the value that is entered there exists in another databank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the constant equal to rangeA.Formula. You can then use the constant wherever you would like within your module or VBA project.

Comment: like this?? i = rangeA . could you please explain that a little further?

Comment: Public rConstants as String
`rConstants = rangeA.Formula`